# Change image using multiple drop down boxes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change an image using two drop down boxes, I'm a complete noob when it comes to jquery/javascript so was wondering if I could get a little help, even if it is just a nudge in the right direction.

SO here is the problem. I want an upholstery color select and a paint color select, both appear on the same product so would be ideal to have 2 dropdown boxes.

The code I have so far is:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var caption=['Default Image Caption',
                'Caption1',
                'Caption2',
                'Caption3',
                'Caption4',
                'Caption5',
                'Caption6',
                'Caption7',
                'Caption8',
                'Caption9'], // This will be your images caption
    bp='images/', //base url of your images
    imgnum=8, //Number of your images. This should match on your comboboxes options.
    thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'), //id of your image that will be changing
    description=document.getElementById('caption'), //id of your caption
    combobox=document.getElementById('paint'); // id of your combobox.
    combobox=document.getElementById('vinyl');

    combobox.onchange=function()
    {
    thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+this.value+name+'.jpg';
    description.innerHTML=caption[this.value];
    }
}
```

and the HTML is

```
<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select id="paint">
<option>Change Picture</option>
<option value="1">Image 1</option>
<option value="2">Image 2</option>
<option value="3">Image 3</option>
<option value="4">Image 4</option>
<option value="5">Image 5</option>
<option value="6">Image 6</option>
<option value="7">Image 7</option>
<option value="8">Image 8</option>
<option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select><br />
<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select id="vinyl">
<option>Change Picture</option>
<option Name="1">Image 1</option>
<option Name="2">Image 2</option>
<option Name="3">Image 3</option>
<option Name="4">Image 4</option>
<option Name="5">Image 5</option>
<option Name="6">Image 6</option>
<option Name="7">Image 7</option>
<option Name="8">Image 8</option>
<option Name="9">Image 9</option>
</select>
```

Okay so with the help of the kind people below I have resolved this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callAFunction(SelectBox)
    {
        var caption=[
            'Default Image Caption',
            'Caption1',
            'Caption2',
            'Caption3',
            'Caption4',
            'Caption5',
            'Caption6',
            'Caption7',
            'Caption8',
            'Caption9'],
        bp='images/',
        imgnum=8,
        thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'),
        description=document.getElementById('caption');
        thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+paint.value+vinyl.value+'.jpg';
        description.innerHTML=caption[SelectBox.value];
    }

</script>

<img src="/images/picture1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb" />

<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select id="paint" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select><br />

<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select id="vinyl" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: ID must be unique bro..

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes and try.

You have same `ID` for two `DOM` that is incorrect.

**In html**

```
<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select class="selection">
    <option>Change Picture</option>
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
</select><br />

<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select class="selection">
    <option>Change Picture</option>
    <option name="1">Image 1</option>
</select>
```

**In JS**

```
combobox=document.getElementById('selection');

to

combobox=document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
```

For checking working capability of `getElementByClassName` [**Click here**](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)

**Response to OP comment.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callAFunction(SelectBox)
    {
        var caption=[
            'Default Image Caption',
            'Caption1',
            'Caption2',
            'Caption3',
            'Caption4',
            'Caption5',
            'Caption6',
            'Caption7',
            'Caption8',
            'Caption9'],
        bp='img/',
        imgnum=8,
        thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'),
        description=document.getElementById('caption');

        thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+SelectBox.value+name+'.jpg';
        description.innerHTML=caption[SelectBox.value];
    }

</script>

<img src="" alt="" id="thumb" />

<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select id="paint" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option>Change Picture</option>
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select><br />

<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select id="vinyl" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option>Change Picture</option>
    <option Name="1">Image 1</option>
    <option Name="2">Image 2</option>
    <option Name="3">Image 3</option>
    <option Name="4">Image 4</option>
    <option Name="5">Image 5</option>
    <option Name="6">Image 6</option>
    <option Name="7">Image 7</option>
    <option Name="8">Image 8</option>
    <option Name="9">Image 9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, this didn't work. I have now changed the ID's in the original post to unique ids, is there a way to call them on the thumb.src which would then change the img?

Comment: actually after combobox=document.getElementById('paint'); this you are replacing that combobox with combobox=document.getElementById('vinyl'); so last one will be set as combobox..

Comment: combobox will be a collection in the second example

Comment: okay, that makes sense is there any way to set them both as comboboxes and then call them in the image name. At the moment i'm using this.value but realise that this will only be applicable to one combobox

Comment: Hi, after playing and using what you provided i can get both dropdowns to change the image but they both change the picture url the same.

Comment: change  onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;" to  onChange="callAFunction(this,imagePath); return false;" and in main function change function callAFunction(this,imagePath){ and in last change bp to imagePath

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
window.onload=function() {
    var caption=['Default Image Caption',
                'Caption11',
                'Caption12',
                'Caption13',
                'Caption14',
                'Caption15',
                'Caption16',
                'Caption17',
                'Caption18',
                'Caption19',
                'Caption21',
                'Caption22',
                'Caption23',
                'Caption24',
                'Caption25',
                'Caption26',
                'Caption27',
                'Caption28',
                'Caption29',
                .
                .
                .
                'Caption99'
      ], // This will be your images caption - no comma on the last
    bp='images/', //base url of your images
    imgnum=8, //Number of your images. This should match on your comboboxes options.
    thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'), //id of your image that will be changing
    description=document.getElementById('caption'), //id of your caption

    var paint=document.getElementById('paint'); // id of your combobox1.
    var vinyl=document.getElementById('vinyl'); // id of your combobox2.

    paint.onchange=vinyl.onchange=function() {
      var val = paint.value+vinyl.value; // "1"+"1"
      thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+val+'.jpg'; // loads images/Picture11.jpg
      description.innerHTML=caption[val]; // loads the 12th text
    }
}
```

or have

```
var vinylCaption["....","....."];
var paintCaption["....","....."];
```

and have

```
description.innerHTML=vinylCaption[vinyl.value] + "/"+paintCaption[paint.value];
```

Comment: Hi, mplungjan, could you please add it to the original code if you could be so kind, just so I can see what's been stripped out and what's been kept?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it's now solved with the help from above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callAFunction(SelectBox)
    {
        var caption=[
            'Default Image Caption',
            'Caption1',
            'Caption2',
            'Caption3',
            'Caption4',
            'Caption5',
            'Caption6',
            'Caption7',
            'Caption8',
            'Caption9'],
        bp='images/',
        imgnum=8,
        thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'),
        description=document.getElementById('caption');
        thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+paint.value+vinyl.value+'.jpg';
        description.innerHTML=caption[SelectBox.value];
    }

</script>

<img src="/images/picture1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb" />

<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select id="paint" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select><br />

<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select id="vinyl" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select>
```

Thank you once again!

Comment: No need to post it again. It is identical in function to my suggestion except mine does not use the inline event which by the way does not need the return false